# Express this matrix in terms of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, products, kronecker-product

I have a block matrix

$$X=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{X}_{1,1}} & {{X}_{1,2}} & \cdots  & {{X}_{1,M}}  \\
   {{X}_{2,1}} & {{X}_{2,2}} & \cdots  & {{X}_{2,M}}  \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & {} & \vdots   \\
   {{X}_{N,1}} & {{X}_{N,2}} & {} & {{X}_{N,M}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$
where each ${{X}_{i,j}}$ is a block. The size of $X$ is $n \times m$, with $N \times M$ blocks. I also have a $N \times M$ matrix:
$$Y=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{y}_{1,1}} & {{y}_{1,2}} & \cdots  & {{y}_{1,M}}  \\
   {{y}_{2,1}} & {{y}_{2,2}} & \cdots  & {{y}_{2,M}}  \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & {} & \vdots   \\
   {{y}_{N,1}} & {{y}_{N,2}} & \cdots  & {{y}_{N,M}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$
where each ${{y}_{i,j}}$ is a scalar.

Now, how can I use matrix $Y$ and $X$, together with some operator (e.g. element-wise multiplication), to represent the following matrix:

$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{y}_{1,1}}{{X}_{1,1}} & {{y}_{1,2}}{{X}_{1,2}} & \cdots  & {{y}_{1,M}}{{X}_{1,M}}  \\
   {{y}_{2,1}}{{X}_{2,1}} & {{y}_{2,2}}{{X}_{2,2}} & \cdots  & {{y}_{2,M}}{{X}_{2,M}}  \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & {} & \vdots   \\
   {{y}_{N,1}}{{X}_{N,1}} & {{y}_{N,2}}{{X}_{N,2}} & \cdots  & {{y}_{N,M}}{{X}_{N,M}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$

Comment: You want a matrix multiplication which gives the final matrix?

Comment: No, it can be any operator

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question. You would like the name of the operator which does the operation you've defined in this question.

Comment: If there is an operator name, that would be perfect. If not, can this resulting matrix be represented as an expression in terms of the symbols $Y$ and $X$ ?

Comment: This actually does have a name.... It is called the Hadamard Product. 
      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Comment: @Volk Hadamard Product requires X and Y to be the same size, but in my expression, they are not.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ahh... I missed that $X$ was a block matrix. My bad...

Comment: Looking at the articles linked from @volk's wikipedia link, there are the Kronecker product, the Khatri-Rao product, and the tensor product. The Kronecker product and the tensor product both reproduce a single block rather than multiplying different blocks. The Khatri-Rao product does something like what is required here but it seems to have some other requirements.

Comment: @SuzuHirose, When each block $X_{i,j}$ over all $(i,j)$ is the same, denoted as $X_{i,j} \equiv X_0 $, the resulting matrix can be represented as $Y \otimes X_0$. However, for the case when the block $X_{i,j}$ is different from each other, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let $A$ be an $n\times m$ matrix of ones. Then
$$
X \cdot (Y \otimes A)
$$
gives your desired matrix where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, and $\cdot$ denotes the Hadamard product.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but both Kronecker and Hadamard are misspelt.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Lol. Thank you. I'll fix it.